# Database choice for creating two connected tables?

Tags: database, database-design, android-sqlite

I have to database tables "Courses" and "Students".

- Courses table has columns ("_id", "course_name", "course_number").
- Student table has columns ("student_name", "student_number", "course_number").

I've created Courses table, but i have problem with creating Students table.

Two classes may have same student, so same student row will exist twice with different `"course_number"`s in Students table. I don't want replicate rows. In this way i can't also make `"student_number"` as `primary key`. Because it will exist twice for multiple classes. How to design this tables, i can't put multiple `"course_number"`s to same columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case of many-to-many, and for that, you'll need a third table between Course and Student. The schema will look something like this:

`Course` table has columns ("course_id", "course_name")

`Student_course` table has columns ("student_id", "course_id");

`Student` table as columns ("student_id", "student_name")

Student_course table has foreign key constraints on both student and course tables.

Example data:

Course:

```
id   |  name
------------------
1    |  Maths
2    |  English
3    |  Science
```

Student

```
id   |  name
---------------
1    |  Tom
2    |  Dick
3    |  Harry
```

Student_course

```
student_id | course_id
------------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 1
3          | 3
```

In this example, Student 1 (Tom) is on courses 1 and 2 (Maths, English),

Student 2 (Dick) is on course 1 only (Maths)

Student 3 (Harry) is on course 3 only (Science)

Comment: so _id is Primary key for "course", student_id is primary key for "student" tables ? Does student_course have to own primary key ?

Comment: student_course has a composite primary key - course_id AND student_id

Answer (score 1):

Student (id, name, number)
Course (id, name, number)
StudentsCourses (student_id, course_id)

You have to make a many to many relation.

Answer (score 1):

There is m to n relationship between Courses and Students.
To map a m to n relationship you need a third table.

```
courses_students
----------------
id_student
id_course

courses
----------------
id_course
// other fields

students
----------------
id_student
// other fields
```